# How do I disassemble my C source in CLion?

Tags: clion

There's a number of reasons I have for wanting to view the ASM of my C program, but from what I'm discovering, it only seems possible to view the ASM of 3rd-party modules that don't have a src.

How can I view the ASM of my src?

Comment: This is not implemented yet, please vote for [CPP-1742 Show assembly view of the file](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-1742) and [CPP-9091 Debugger: Disassemble on demand](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-9091)

Comment: thanks, will do ;)

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, but found a solution for clion. It however requires that you have the GDB debuggger.

1. Set a breakpoint in the function that you want to disassemble
2. Run the debugger
3. When the breakpoint is hit, look down on in the debugger window, on the right panel, you should see GDB. Click on it
4. Type: `disassemble`
5. The disassembly of the function should be printed out in the same panel
6. Enjoy.

Comment: This also works for lldb, type `di -f` to disassemble the current frame. See: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html